# Send SMS with another number as sender

Tags: android

Is it possible to send an SMS from an Android app and change the sender number, so that the receiver will see the SMS as coming from someone else?

I'm not doing this for pranks or illegal systems, it's something necessary.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, and would find it highly questionable if it were.

If you're simply looking to give someone the ability to send a message to a number using your app as a service. Then try using Twilio www.twilio.com or something similar where you can pick a number and send message to others. Although you will be paying for the SMS's that are sent and this may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you need a sms server/gateway or an online provider which does it for you. You could even enter text as your number (companies like facebook and google do this).

A site I found: http://api.textmagic.com/